# Why can't I access automatically generated default method in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm investigating kotlin and now curious about next thing:

I have next class:

```
class Test5 {
    fun x(x: Int = 5) { }
}
```

I see in bytecode that next method is generated to bridge default values:

```
  public static synthetic bridge x$default(LTest5;IILjava/lang/Object;)V
    ILOAD 2
    ICONST_1
    IAND
    IFEQ L0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 4 L1
    ICONST_5
    ISTORE 1
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    ILOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL Test5.x (I)V
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 4
```

But in Intelij i can't call this method directly. Why it's impossible? Is it only IDE trick?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have you annotate that with `@JvmOverloads` in order to call that from Java.

From the [documentation for `@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation):

> Normally, if you write a Kotlin function with default parameter values, it will be visible in Java only as a full signature, with all parameters present. If you wish to expose multiple overloads to Java callers, you can use the `@JvmOverloads` annotation.
>
> The annotation also works for constructors, static methods etc. It can't be used on abstract methods, including methods defined in interfaces.

Example:

```
class Test5 {
    @JvmOverloads
    fun x(x: Int = 5) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Todd, I know it. I'm just curious how this behaviour is achieved - the method is in bytecode, but i can't call it...

Comment: @the_kaba That's because the `synthetic` modifier, this means that compilers should ignore the method, it's also used for when you extend for example ArrayList&lt;String> (not that you *should* do that), it generates a synthetic `add(Object obj)` method, that calls `add((String)obj)`

Comment: Ferrybig, thanks for the answer. Not it's cleaner. So the method just not visible for IDE because it appears after compilation..

Comment: The method is not visible for the IDE because it's marked as synthetic. At what time it appears is irrelevant.